# Neo4j recommended settings

Tags: optimization, neo4j

I have rented a Joyent SmartOS machine to host a Neo4j server for my project.

The machine is the *Extra Small 0.5 GB (1 vCPU)* which means it has 512 Megabytes RAM.

What would you recommend instead of the following default *neostore.* settings?

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=50M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M
```

Some CPU info if needed:

```
# psrinfo -pv
The physical processor has 6 cores and 12 virtual processors (1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (1 13)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (3 15)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (5 17)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (7 19)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (9 21)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (11 23)
    x86 (GenuineIntel 206C2 family 6 model 44 step 2 clock 2400 MHz)
      Intel(r) Xeon(r) CPU           E5645  @ 2.40GHz
The physical processor has 6 cores and 12 virtual processors (0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (0 12)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (2 14)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (4 16)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (6 18)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (8 20)
  The core has 2 virtual processors (10 22)
    x86 (GenuineIntel 206C2 family 6 model 44 step 2 clock 2400 MHz)
      Intel(r) Xeon(r) CPU           E5645  @ 2.40GHz
```

Comment: depends on how big your DB is. The caching information you set there is the recommendation of how big your files are, to help you size your cache, but if you have more information then memory, you're going to need to tweek the cache to be small.

Comment: for now my data ammount is small, but let's say I have 250mb of data?

Comment: You can find out more about caching here. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html

Comment: depending on the number of nodes, relations and properties. in the link @Nicholas posted above you will see how much memory does each entity take. than, you can better calculate, whether you want to lift up the node cache instead of rels, or otherwise, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `neostore.xxxx.mapped_memory` settings in your config should ideally match the size of the respective file in your graph.db directory.

Given that you have 512 MB RAM available and your graph is ~250 MB, gives you ~250MB for OS *and* JVM Heap which I consider too small.

If your box had 2G, I'd calculate:

- 250 MB mapped memory
- 1 GB Java heap (aka -Xmx1g -Xms1g)
- 750 MB OS (the rest)

Comment: I now have 32G so it's very fast as I still only use it for dev of [Konfect](http://www.konfect.com/) but I'll need to fine tune soon.